# Adding a number to number results in NaN in my program. WHY?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add secondsPassed to timePassed but when doing so I get NaN.

I can't find anything wrong so why is timePassed = NaN when adding secondsPassed to it?

```js
var secondsPassed = 0;
var oldTimeStamp = 0;
let fps;
var posX = 0, posY = 0;
var timePassed = 0.0;

setTimeout(gameLoop, 100);

function gameLoop(timeStamp){
    
    //seconds since last frame
    secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
    oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    
    // Move forward in time with a maximum amount
    secondsPassed = Math.min(secondsPassed, 0.1);
    
    //calculate fps
    fps = Math.round(1 / secondsPassed);
    
    //run game functions
    update(secondsPassed);
    
    
    //loop again
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function update(secondsPassed){
    
    console.log(secondsPassed);
    timePassed += secondsPassed;
    console.log(timePassed);
    
    
    
    posX = 200 * timePassed;
    posY = 400;
    
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to initialize `oldTimeStamp` before doing math on it so NaN is expected.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem i'm still getting NaN from timePassed

Comment: `setTimeout(gameloop)` will call the gameloop function ***without any argument***

Comment: Adding to the comment above, change: `window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);` to `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => gameLoop(timeStamp));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to pass `timeStamp` argument to `gameLoop()` function. Passing it fixes the issue. Also make sure, your `oldTimeStamp` is initialized.
`+new Date()` is a way to create a timestamp from `Date` object.

```js
let secondsPassed;
let oldTimeStamp = +new Date() - (60*5);
let fps;
let frame;
let posX = 0, posY = 0;
let timePassed = 0;

setTimeout(gameLoop(+new Date()), 1000);

function update(secondsPassed){
    console.log("sec: " + secondsPassed);
    timePassed += secondsPassed;
    console.log("time: " + timePassed);
    
    posX = 200 * timePassed;
    posY = 400;
    
}

function gameLoop(timeStamp){
    
    //seconds since last frame
    secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
    oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    
    // Move forward in time with a maximum amount
    secondsPassed = Math.min(secondsPassed, 0.1);
    
    //calculate fps
    fps = Math.round(1 / secondsPassed);
    frame++;
    
    update(secondsPassed);
    //draw();
    //run game functions
    
    //loop again
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.min returns NaN if any of its parameters is converted into numbers. So, check your code before that, what value is passed due to which it gives NaN.
Also, read this [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min#return_value)
May be the one of the timestamp is a object type.